# Creating a function for dynamic string input

Tags: python, function

Hi i am trying to create a function which allow string input as below:

```
def change_template(condition):
    template='''
             <div style="background:<%= 
             (function colorfromint(){
              if(condition){ #change the condition inside here
              return("green")}
                }()) %>; 
            color: black"> 
        <%= value %>
        </div>
        '''
    return template
```

So whenever I input condition into change_template function, let say change_template(**'A' < 'B'**) then the condition would be

```
template='''
          <div style="background:<%= 
          (function colorfromint(){
          if('A' < 'B'){ #change the condition inside here
          return("green")}
          }()) %>; 
          color: black"> 
          <%= value %>
          </div>
            '''
```

Comment: Can you please explain the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `"'A' < 'B'"`?

Comment: Okay, so the question is how to modify the "template" string so as to insert the content from `condition`? Or just what exactly?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yup to modify the template based on the content from condition

Comment: Maybe try adding your html into 1 line join the strings either side of `condition` like `'<div>...' + condition + '...</div>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to set your condition inside your template, or you can use `format` like what @Daniel said.

```
def change_template(condition):
  template='''
        <div style="background:<%= 
        (function colorfromint(){
        if('''+condition+'''){ #change the condition inside here
        return("green")}
          }()) %>; 
      color: black"> 
  <%= value %>
  </div>
  '''
  return template

print(change_template("'A'<'B'"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `format` method for strings.  Here's an example.

```
x='hello'
y='foo {} bar'.format(x)
print(y)
```

This produces

```
foo hello bar
```

EDIT:

If your Python version is at least 3.6, you could also use f-strings.  E.g.,

```
x='hello'
y=f'foo {x} bar'
print(y)
```

Same output.